# Use Measure as slicer is not working properly in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix with 3 levels:

1. 1st level Reseller;
2. 2nd level Contract Name;
3. 3rd level Year Hierarchy: Year, Quarter, and Month.

And I have the measure `Revenue = SUM ( 'Fact Invoice'[Invoice Amount] )`

I created the Revenue measure as a filter [source video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZAL-QPn5Zc):

I created a calculated table:

```
Revenue Filter = GENERATESERIES(0, [Revenue], 100)
```

and then created this measure:

```
Revenue Filter Measure = VAR MinValue = MIN ( 'Revenue Filter'[Value] ) 
VAR MaxValue = MAX ( 'Revenue Filter'[Value] ) 
VAR currentMeasure = [Revenue] 
RETURN IF ( currentMeasure >= MinValue && currentMeasure <= MaxValue, 1, 0 )
```

In the visual filter, I set this measure = 1 so that the slicer could filter the matrix, and it is filtering.

The problem is that it doesn't show the data correctly.

I tried to create this measure:

```
Revenue Filter AGG measure = 
VAR MinValue =
    MIN ( 'Revenue Filter'[Value] )
VAR MaxValue =
    MAX ( 'Revenue Filter'[Value] )
VAR currentMeasure = [Revenue]
--VAR CurrentContract = MAX('Dim Contract'[Contract Intermediary Account Name 1])
 
RETURN
IF (
        ISINSCOPE('Dim Contract'[Contract Intermediary Account Name 1]),
        CALCULATE(
            IF (
                currentMeasure >= MinValue && currentMeasure <= MaxValue,
                1,
                0
            ),
            ALL('Date')
        )
        ,0
    )
```

to then filter it in the filter pane = 1, to give me the correct filtered values, but without success.

As shown in the image below, for Reseller 3, it is correct because the total is between the values I set in the slicer (between 2k - 5k).

But for Resellers 1 and 2, it is not correct because the total is greater than the values I am filtering in the slicer. However, since the other levels have values that match the revenue filter, they are appearing.

That is, for Reseller 1, everything should be 0 because the total does not correspond to the revenue slicer filtering.

The same issue may occur for Reseller 3, for example, having a month with 300€, January 2891.36€, and February 300€; this 300€ value should not appear either.

[image]

Sample data:

```
Reseller,Contract Hierarchy,Year,Quarter,Month,Revenue
Reseller 2,Contract_1,2023,Q1,March,€ 3 692,09
Reseller 2,Contract_1,2023,Q1,February,€ 3 508,58
Reseller 3,Contract_3,2023,Q1,January,€ 2 891,36
Reseller 1,Contract_2,2023,Q2,May,€ 2 869,66
Reseller 2,Contract_2,2023,Q4,November,€ 2 187,18
Reseller 3,Contract_2,2023,Q4,October,€ 2 146,18
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
Revenue Filter AGG measure = 
    VAR MinValue = MIN ( 'Revenue Filter'[Value] )
    VAR MaxValue = MAX ( 'Revenue Filter'[Value] )
    VAR _currentRe = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Reseller])
    VAR currentMeasure = [Revenue]
    VAR _sumRe = CALCULATE(
        currentMeasure,
        FILTER(
            ALLSELECTED('Table'),
            'Table'[Reseller] = _currentRe
        )
    )
    RETURN
        IF(
            _sumRe <= _maxValue && _sumRe >= _minValue,
            IF(
                currentMeasure  <= _maxValue && currentMeasure  >= _minValue,
                1,
                0
            ),
            0
        )
```

The result is as follow:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V12m.png]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).